# If a and b are roots of polynomials P and Q, then what polynomials are a+b and ab a roots of?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ are roots of polynomials $P$ and $Q$ with rational coefficients, is there an algorithm / formula / process for finding polynomials with rational coefficients for which $a+b$ and/or $ab$ are roots of?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Number_theory

Comment: Look up the *resultant* of two polynomials.  The resultant of
$P(y)$ and $Q(x-y)$ with respect to $y$ is a polynomial in $x$
whose roots are $a+b$ where $P(a)=Q(b)=0$.  Changing $Q(x-y)$ to
$y^{\deg(Q)} Q(x/y)$ yields a polynomial with roots $ab$.
[*EDIT*: I see that the same formulas appear in the link posted by **Wojowu**
while I was writing this answer.]

Comment: Alternatively, look up "companion matrix" (of a polynomial), "Kronecker product" (of two matrices) and "Kronecker sum" (of two matrices). Then find two matrices with rational entries that have $a$ and $b$ as eigenvalues (you can construct them as companion matrices), and take their Kronecker product and Kronecker sum.

Comment: Thanks, these all sound like what I was after.